# How to define generic template signature

Tags: c++, c++11

I have 2 classes where the functions are copy and paste. The only difference between these classes is class each inherit. These super classes have same call signatures, but the constructors are different.

I was trying to do something like:

```
template<class BaseClass>
class IGenericPart : public BaseClass {
 public:
  int commonCall1() { return 10; }
  int commonCall2() { return 44; }
};

class A : public IGenericPart<RealBaseClass1> {
 public:
  A(int x) : IGenericPart<RealBaseClass1> (x, b) {}
};

class B : public IGenericPart<RealBaseClass2> {
 public:
  B(string z) : IGenericPart<RealBaseClass2> (z, anothertype2, anothertype2) {}
};
```

But I don't know how to make the `IGenericPart` class having a forward constructor based on the generic `BaseClass`.
So basically, I need that the `IGenericPart<RealBaseClass1>` and `IGenericPart<RealBaseClass2>` having different constructors.

Comment: Are `RealBaseClass1/2` derived from `BaseClass`? And btw, your `BaseClass` is a parent of `IGenericPart`, so you should be able to invoke its constructor in the constructor of `IGenericPart` as `IGenericPart(): BaseClass(parameters){...}`. Is this what you're after?

Comment: I could only do IGenericPart(): BaseClass(parameters) if `IGenericPart()` also received the parameters. let me edit to try to make ir clearer that the constructors are actually different.

Comment: This is answered by: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394492/does-inheriting-constructors-work-with-templates-in-c0x

Comment: NO it didn't, my question is different, I want to have `IGenericPart<RealBaseClass1>` and `IGenericPart<RealBaseClass2>` with different signatures for constructors.

Comment: @TylerMcHenry, please remove duplicate or explain why it was answered in that question.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, your question is actually simpler than what I thought it was a duplicate of. I've removed my dupe vote and will provide an answer below.

Comment: Wouldn't your problem be solved by using variadic templates and perfect forwarding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing a `using` declaration.

When class `IGenericPart<>` inherits from `BaseClass` it does not automatically inherit the constructors from `BaseClass`. To inherit constructors, you must do so explicitly with a `using` declaration, like so:

```
template<class BaseClass>
class IGenericPart : public BaseClass {
 public:
  using BaseClass::BaseClass;
  // etc ...
};
```

This then creates constructors for `IGenericPart<BaseClass>` that are in correspondence with  and which forward to each constructor of `BaseClass`, so the initialization lists of `A` and `B` will work as expected.

Note that constructor inheritence is a C++11 feature, so you must be compiling in C++11 mode with a compiler that supports C++11 for this to work.

Comment: This is great! I was really missing the `using` keyword. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use c++11 for some reasone you can get it to work by adding the following, clunky bits, to IGenericPart:

```
template<class BaseClass>
class IGenericPart: public BaseClass {
  public:
    template <typename A>
    IGenericPart(A a) : BaseClass(a) {}

    template <typename A, typename B>
    IGenericPart(A a, B b) : BaseClass(a, b) {}

    template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
    IGenericPart(A a, B b, C c) : BaseClass(a, b, c) {}
}
```