# Constructor inheritance for class derived from template class in visual studio 2015 rc

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, constructor, visual-studio-2015

According to the [page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/04/29/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-rc.aspx) of msvs2015rc new features constructor inheritance should be supported. Yes, it works in simple cases like this:

```
struct B { 
    B(int) {}
};
struct D : B {
    using B::B; // now we can create D object with B's constructor 
};
```

But if I'll try to create more complex example:

```
template <class T>
struct B
{
    B(int) {} 
};

template <template <class> class C, class T>
struct D : C<T>
{
    using C<T>::C;
};

int main() {

    D<B,int> d(42);
    return 0;
}
```

I've got compiler errors:

- `error C2039: 'C': is not a member of 'B<T>'`
- `error C2873: 'C': symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration`
- `error C2664: 'D<B,int>::D(D<B,int> &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'const D<B,int> &'`

I can eliminate these errors if and only if rename template template class `C` to `B`:

```
template <template <class> class B, class T>
struct D : B<T>
{
    using B<T>::B;
};
```

I think this is a compiler bug because all of these codes well compiled with [gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d624cdfc298d4ae7)/[clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d71e80d945650471).

Do anybody has another opinion about this issue?

Comment: Maybe you are missing `template` or `typename` somewhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bug in the MSVC and it also appears in the latest version which they provide online. So, please, submit a bug report. Relevant discussion might be found in [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394492/does-inheriting-constructors-work-with-templates-in-c0x) SO question. It contains some excerpts from the standard which explain why it should work.