# Preserve default constructor in derived classes

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

How to preserve the default constructor in the derived class, without adding   `Derived() = default;` in the derived class?

```
struct Base
{
  Base() = default;
};

struct Derived : Base
{
  using Base::Base;

  explicit Derived(int) {}
};

int main()
{
  // Compilation error here
  Derived d;
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. What error are you getting?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to explicitly default the default constructor?

Comment: @NicolBolas not really, but since I have many derived classes I'd like to avoid many explicitly default c'tors..

Comment: Compiles for me with GCC  7.2.0.

Comment: Doesn't compile with MSVC: https://godbolt.org/g/Byh8y7

Comment: @hlt it should with c++14 or c++17 standard

Comment: That's the issue - it should (assuming Clang and GCC are right), but it doesn't, even with `/std:c++latest`… MSVC bug?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31232592/constructor-inheritance-for-class-derived-from-template-class-in-visual-studio-2

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bug. It works with later versions of gcc. I tried 7.1, it worked. Worked with clang as well. Which compiler you are using?

See:

[Constructor inheritance for class derived from template class in visual studio 2015 rc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31232592/constructor-inheritance-for-class-derived-from-template-class-in-visual-studio-2)